# How to get Entities based on field values in another Entitiy in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have entity `Product` and entity `Subcategory`:

**Subcategory.php**

```
namespace Project\Entities;    

/**
 * Subcategory 
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="subcategories")
 *
 */
class Subcategory {
/**
 * 
 * @Id 
 * @GeneratedValue 
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @var integer $id
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string")
 * @var string $name
 */
public $name;
}
```

**Product.php**

```
namespace Project\Entities;

/**
 * 
 * Product 
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="products")
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * 
     * @Id 
     * @GeneratedValue 
     * @Column(type="integer",length=16)
     * @var integer $id
     */
    public  $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @Column(type="integer",length=3)
     * @var integer $id_subcat
     */
    public $id_subcat;

    /**
     * 
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var integer $name
     */
    public $name;


    /**
     * 
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var integer $available
     */
    public $available;
}
```

I would like to get all `Subcategories` that have `Products` `available` field equal 1.
Ergo. Get Subcategories that have only available products in them.

I know how to write `SQL` query for that but I don't know how to achieve this in `DQL`.

Should I provide some additional annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to begin by declaring the relationship in your entities. I am going to assume that your Subcategory can have many Products (one-to-many):

I haven't tested this code obviously, so I apologize if there are some errors, this is off the top of my head mostly.

```
/**
 * Subcategory 
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="subcategories")
 *
 */
class Subcategory {
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\Entities\Product", mappedBy="id_subcat")
     * @var Products[]
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
             $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Leaving out rest of class for simplicity...
}


/**
 * 
 * Product 
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="products")
 */
class Product {

    // Rest of class....

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\Entities\Subcategory", inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_subcat", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $id_subcat = null;

}
```

** Then to query, in SF2, it would be like this:

```
/* var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em */
$dql = "SELECT p FROM Project\Entities\Product p JOIN p.subcategoryId sc ORDER BY p.name ASC"
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$results = $query->getResult();
$products = array();
```

Now, because we have protected variables in our entity, you'd want setters and getters on your objects. 
This can be very helpful for formatting how content is returned, etc.

```
foreach ($results as $product)
{
     $products[] = array("id" => $product->getId(),
                         "name" => $product->getName(),
                         "subCategory" => $product->getSubcategoryId()                           
                          );
 }
```

Comment: Nice detail in this response, especially the last section.

Comment: Thank for information about relations between tables, but actually I was hoping to get `Subcategories` in this query. I clarified my question to specify exactly what I meant.

Comment: I don't know which field you're using in your Products table to check availability... so I will just call the field availability.

`$dql = "SELECT sc FROM Project\Entities\Subcategory sc JOIN sc.products p WHERE p.availability = 1 ORDER BY p.name ASC"`

Comment: I've field 'available'. Will check your DQL in a moment :)

Comment: I've checked it and it seems that product is missing. The query produced SQL error. From MySql log the query looks like this: `SELECT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.name AS name1 FROM subcategories s0_ INNER JOIN  WHERE p1_.available = 1 ORDER BY p1_.name ASC`

Comment: Did you use `sc.products` or `sc.product`? The DQL query uses the variables from your Entity to map to the fields in your database. What was the SQL error?

Comment: I've used `SELECT sc FROM Project\Entity\Subcategory sc JOIN sc.products p WHERE p.available = 1 ORDER BY p.name ASC` and the error was `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p1_.available = 1 ORDER BY p1_.name ASC' at line 1'`

Comment: Do you have available listed as a property in your entity? Also, try chopping off the ORDER BY at the end, and seeing if the query works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4594/discussion-between-pixel-and-kurt-funai)

Answer (score 0):

Read about association mapping: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html